# What is this building called? (It was built in 2002)

Tags: building

[image]

I have tried google image'ing it, but it doesn't work. Also it is a building that has a history as far as from 3th century before anno domini.

Answer (score 13):

Looks pretty much like the [Bibliotheca Alexandrina](https://archnet.org/sites/4370/media_contents/36230)?

> [image]

The historical predecessor was the [Library of Alexandria:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria)

> Established   Probably during the reign of Ptolemy II Philadelphus (285–246 BC)

And the modern building [Bibliotheca Alexandrina:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliotheca_Alexandrina)

> 16 October 2002; 16 years ago

Viewed from Google Earth:

> [image]
>   [image]